# wget with subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess, wget

I'm working on a domain fronting project. Basically I'm trying to use the `subprocess.call()` function to interpret the following command:
`wget -O - https://fronteddomain.example --header 'Host: targetdomain.example'`

With the proper domains, I know how to domain front, that is not the problem. Just need some help with writing using the python `subprocess.call()` function with wget.

Comment: What have you done so far that did not work? Which part of it is not covered by documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?

Comment: Why do a `subprocess.call()` to launch `wget` when you have HTTP client libraries available in Python, starting with `requests` (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've been working on domain fronting using curl and wget through the CLI, so I just looked up a way to run a command in python. I will look into the `requests` library. I just need the ability to manipulate Host headers.

Comment: Manipulating headers should not be a problem, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers.  By using an internal library instead of an external command you gain: more control, more performances, more portability (ex: running your code on an host that does not have `curl` or `wget` installed) and better security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using curl:

`call(["curl", "-s", "-H" "Host: targetdomain.example", "-H", "Connection: close", "frontdomain.example"])`